# Android (Verizon) Push Mail from enterprize server

Tags: email, android

Our Company currently have blackberry phones, and I would like to add a android (Verizon) to the mix.  We are a Enterprise 2003 mail server (windows)

My admin is stuck with the possibility of using a blackberry enterprise mail server along with a push server for Android phone.  Is there a software package out there (open source or pay) that will push mail to android phone, but be compatible or replace the blackberry mail server.

I'm not sure if I'm asking the right question?

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Do you mean Exchange 2003 mail server?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Sorry, I'm not up on all the correct software.

Answer (score 1):

Leave your current Exchange Server as is for all the blackberry devices.  Android has software that will work with Exchange and allow you to do push email.

- http://www.dintz.com/push-exchange-e-mail-hits-android-market/
- http://www.mobilitysite.com/2009/03/android-gets-push-email-support/

Comment: Is it true that Verizon will charge $15.00 to Exchange user to push email?  Not sure if this is correct?

Comment: Only for corporate accounts. But if you are a Joe Nobody and want access to your company/personal/other Exchange server, then you can still do it with just the $30/month data plan, so there is no $15 charge/month.

Comment: I use a Android phone with push emails and I don't pay the extra $15. Just don't tell them you are using it for Exchange.